# Executing s4 methods for all classes of an object?

Tags: xml, r, r-s4

I have an object `C` which inherits class `B` which inherits class `A`, 
along with a method for each class, e.g.,

```
setClass("A", representation(a = 'numeric'))
setClass("B", representation(b = 'numeric'), contains="A")
setClass("C", representation(c = 'numeric'), contains="B")
```

and methods

```
setGeneric("toXML", function(obj, node) standardGeneric("toXML"))
setMethod("toXML", 
          signature("A", "XMLInternalElementNode"), 
          function(obj, node) addAttributes(node, a = obj@a))
setMethod("toXML", 
          signature("B", "XMLInternalElementNode"), 
          function(obj, node) addAttributes(node, b = obj@b))
setMethod("toXML", 
          signature("C", "XMLInternalElementNode"), 
          function(obj, node) addAttributes(node, c = obj@c))
```

That is, each class represents a possible attribute an XML node can have.
I want to write a method (or coercion) that would perform these functions
for all matching classes.

Of course the way I've written it, doing

```
library(XML)
obj <- new("C", a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
toXML(obj, newXMLNode("node"))
```

Just returns:

```
<node c="3"/>
```

Instead of

```
<node a="1" b="2" c="3"/>
```

What would be a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by using `callNextMethod()`?

```
setGeneric("toXML", function(obj, node) standardGeneric("toXML"))
setMethod("toXML", 
          signature("A", "XMLInternalElementNode"), 
          function(obj, node) addAttributes(node, a = obj@a))
setMethod("toXML", 
          signature("B", "XMLInternalElementNode"), 
          function(obj, node) {
              node <- callNextMethod()            ## <- Line I added
              addAttributes(node, b = obj@b)
              })
setMethod("toXML", 
          signature("C", "XMLInternalElementNode"), 
          function(obj, node) {
              node <- callNextMethod()            ## <- Line I added 
              addAttributes(node, c = obj@c)
          })

## Trying it out
obj <- new("C", a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
toXML(obj, newXMLNode("node"))
# <node a="1" b="2" c="3"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant. After reading the documentation I'm still unclear why you assign `callNextMethod` to `node`.  Seems weird to me; looks like this is just overwriting one of the arguments, even though it isn't?

Comment: @cboettig Thanks. You need to (locally) overwrite `node` with the results returned by `callNextMethod()` or else those results will 'vanish into the ether'. There's no fancy principle here, just R's standard philosophy of not performing assignment unless explicitly instructed to do so (i.e. not as a side effect). It's the same reason you'd do this: `f <- function(x) {x<-x^2; x+3}` rather than this: `f <- function(x) {x^2; x+3}` if you want that `x^2` to have any effect on the returned value of a call to `f`.

Comment: Right, but this case is a lot more subtle to me than the x case, where you replace a numeric with a numeric.  `addAttributes` expects the `node` argument to be an "XMLInternalElementNode" class.  How does a call to `callNextMethod`, with no arguments, know to return an object of this class?

Comment: @josh-obrien what does callNextMethod actually return in this case?  Unlike `x<-x^2` I can't evaluate it outside the function and get the same effect.  Is it using the function environment to figure out what to do?

Comment: @cboettig -- `callNextMethod()` returns an object of class `"XMLInternalElementNode"`. Try inserting a `browser()` call just above either of the two lines I marked with `## <- Line I added`. Then call `toXML(obj, newXMLNode("node"))`. Once you're dumped into the browser, you can call `callNextMethod()` and look at what it produces. I'm guessing that (together with a close reading of `?callNextMethod`'s **Description** section) be a faster way for you to *see* what's going on than any explanation I'd give. (Still, I'll be happy to help if you're still puzzled after trying that out.)

Comment: @josh-obrien Brilliant, I see, it is simply getting it's return type from that returned by the previous `setMethod` function, of course.  Very clever.

Comment: Bingo. Glad you appreciate that too ;)